A grid made of "building blocks"
There are six colors used in this puzzle as you can see - black, green, orange, red, white and yellow. I tried to make them colorblind-friendly and hopefully everyone can see which color is which (especially when zooming in).
The answer to this puzzle is a suitable word.

What do I call this puzzle?

Thought I was getting somewhere by trying to solve this as rot13(n fhqbxh - ohg ng guvf cbvag (hayrff V'ir tbar jebat fbzrjurer, juvpu vf cbffvoyr) gurer ner zhygvcyr fbyhgvbaf vs nccylvat bayl gur onfvp ehyrf. Creuncf n inevngvba ba gur ehyrf vf erdhverq, fbzrubj hfvat gur yvarf qenja ba vg? Nygreangviryl, gubfr jvyy or sbe fbzr xvaq bs anzr rkgenpgvba ng gur raq. Rvgure jnl, abg fher vs gur fhqbxh ebhgr vf n qrnq raq - gur vavgvny bevragngvba whfg frrzrq n cresrpg svg...)

@Stiv I think this would be an incredible coincidence if you were on the wrong track here.

That must be right, @Stiv. With your idea, I can imagine what the colours are and how the extraction works.

@MOehm I'd love to see it. I've re-run my solve and got to the same point, with at least 2 valid solutions using base rules only, so something needs adding! :)

I have no solution to show, @Stiv, only explanations for the colours. For what it's worth, rot13(Gur pbybhef ner gur cevzrf va Evpuneq-bs-Lbex beqre; fcyvg qbgf ner cbjref bs gjb naq guerr; oynpx vf gur fcrpvny inyhr bar. Nsgre gur tevq vf fbyirq, yrggref pna or rkgenpgrq sebz gur yvarf ivn gurve nfpvv pbqrf.)

(Okay, I get to the same point as you and at least my second brash assumption is wrong.)

@Stiv Ahh, I thought it definitely was unique as the online tool I used only provided one solution. Well, let me add a color or two to make it unique

@MOehm You got what they represent and the correct order too!

(@Stiv, I've got an answer now, but I got there only because you shared your findings. Do you mind if I post my answer?)

@MOehm Please feel free :)

This puzzle is a ...

 ... Primoku.

Stiv observed ...

 ... that this 9×9 grid is actually a sudoku puzzle:



We can solve it ...

 ... and get this:



 (There's no [grid-deduction] tag, so I don't feel obliged to explain how I got the answer. There are enough cells filled in and it isn't very hard.)

The name of the game

 Several cells are connected and that is probably how to get the single-word answer to this puzzle.

 A typical sudoku uses the numbers 1 to 9. This is a typical sudoku, because the circles repreent the numbers from 1 to 9.

 There are solid circles in black, red, orange, yellow and green. In addition, there are red circles split into two and three, orange circles split into two and a combination of red and orange half-circles.

 Let's write out the prime factorizations of the numbers from 1 to 9:

   1   2   3   2·2   5   2·3   7   2·2·2   3·3

 We can see that different sectors of the circles are to be multiplied. The colours of the rainbow red, orange, yellow, green represent the primes 2, 3, 5, and 7. (Blue, indigo and violet for 11, 13 and 17 are not needed here.) One, which is neither prime nor composite is black.

What's the word?

 The links between the circles describe two-digit numbers. (The three joined numbers are two separate links that happen to join the same circle; the "interior link" in the top right corner is a single-digit number.)

 The numbers are 9, 18, 21, 16, 15, 11 and 13. These are, of course, indices into the alphabet to get the letters I, R, U, P, O, K and M. We can anagram those to get a lovely name for this puzzle involving prime numbers and sudoku: Primoku.

Final remarks

 I guess that the building blocks referred to in the title are the prime factors, since they make up all of the hidden numbers, exept 1. The long preamble about not using many colours is probably a hint at primary colours and intended as a hint towards primes. (Orange isn't a primary clour, though, and I can't see any hint regarding the rainbow.)

 Finally, I hadn't seen what this is about until Stiv posted his compelling findings, so thanks for that. After that, and knowing about Prim3numbah's penchant for prime numbers (how come?), it all fell into place. (I first thought that ASCII values must be involved, because of the triple link at the bottom, but that gotresolved quickly.)


Ah, that all makes sense now! Glad this is solved - thanks for following the thought process to the end of the path that I couldn't see :)

They come in handy quite often :) Well done!
